# Python how to replace string through dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

EX)

```
import re

nodeDic = {"ABC-3K":"True","TTR":"True"}<br />
address = "ABC-3K and TTR"

result = eval(re.sub(r"\b(\w+)\b", lambda m: nodeDic.get(m.group(1), m.group(1)), address))<br />

print(result)
--->True and True
```

but I have errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/IT1_807_6/PycharmProjects/choonlog/Test/eval.py", line 6, in
>   
>       result = eval(re.sub(r"\b(\w+)\b", lambda m: nodeDic.get(m.group(1), m.group(1)), address))   File "", line
>   1
>       GSK-3b and True
>            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**When I remove hyphen(-) no matters. But when I use hyphen(-) symbol it matters. I have to use the hyphen(-)**

Comment: Don't use eval, what are you trying to do? I guarantee there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I have to execute each boolean logic expression given by multiline-text 
EX)
modelText = '''
A = A and B or C\n
B = A or C\n
...\n
...\n
'''

Comment: So each value in the dictionary has a string representation of a bool?

Comment: Yes. There are no better ways to solve that without 'eval'

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: OH, I mistyped. I edited. I want to replace "ABC-3K and TTR" to True and True(boolean logic expression).

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a regex that does what you want, but it is a complete mess:

```
 (?:(?<=\A)|(?<=\s))(.+?)(?=\Z|\s)
```

If you use this regex:

```
nodeDic = {"ABC-3K":"True","TTR":"True"}
address = "ABC-3K and TTR"

result = eval(re.sub(r"(?:(?<=\A)|(?<=\s))(.+?)(?=\Z|\s)", lambda m: nodeDic.get(m.group(1),m.group(1)), address))

print(result) # prints True
```